# How to multiply each row of an array with all rows of an array element-wise in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I need to multiply each row of an array **A** with all rows of an array **B** element-wise. For instance, let's say we have the following arrays:

```
A = np.array([[1,5],[3,6]])
B = np.array([[4,2],[8,2]])
```

I want to get the following array **C**:

```
C = np.array([[4,10],[8,10],[12,12],[24,12]])
```

I could do this by using *for* loop but I think there could be a better way to do it.

**EDIT:** I thought of repeating and tiling but my arrays are not that small. It could create some memory problem.

Comment: While Divakar correctly deduced what you wanted, you really should have shown us the looped code.  Or a (2,2,2) version of `C` rather than the (4,2).  There are various ways that rows of `A` can be combined with the rows of `B` (e.g. `np.kron(A,B)`).

Comment: I'm sorry. I upvoted it but I forgot to accept it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) extending dims for `A` to `3D` with `None/np.newaxis`, perform the elementwise multiplication and reshape back to `2D` -

```
(A[:,None]*B).reshape(-1,B.shape[1])
```

which essentially would be -

```
(A[:,None,:]*B[None,:,:]).reshape(-1,B.shape[1])
```

Schematically put, it's :

```
A     :  M x 1 x N
B     :  1 x K x N
out   :  M x K x N
```

Final reshape to merge last two axes and give us `(M x K*N)` shaped `2D` array.

---

We can also use `einsum` to perform the extension to `3D` and elementwise multiplication in one function call -

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->ikj',A,B).reshape(-1,B.shape[1])
```