# Multiplying each row of an array by a list, element-wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a 3 dimensionnal numpy array and a list which look like this:

```
array = [  [[1,2,3,10], [4,5,6,11], [7,8,9,12]],   [[1,2,3,10], [4,5,6,11], [7,8,9,12]] ]
lst = [50, 60, 70]
```

I would like to multiply each column of my array by the list, element-wise. Hence, the result would look like:

```
result = [[[50, 100, 150, 500], [240, 300, 360, 660], [490, 560, 630, 840]], [same]]
```

It seems really simple to me, but I can't figure it out and I get lost in all the methods available to multiply arrays.

`np.dot()` does not work because : `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'`
I think by comprehension might be the worst way to do it (real length on axis 0 is 1088).

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219864/how-to-multiply-each-row-of-an-array-with-all-rows-of-an-array-element-wise-in-p) but I basically don't understand anything.

Comment: For future reader, you may want to edit and change the `[0,1,3]` value of your expected result from `720` to `660`, since, unless I am mistaken (and so is mozway), what is expected here is `11*60=660`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your list to array and use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
out = array * np.array(lst)[:,None]
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 50, 100, 150, 500],
        [240, 300, 360, 660],
        [490, 560, 630, 840]],

       [[ 50, 100, 150, 500],
        [240, 300, 360, 660],
        [490, 560, 630, 840]]])
```

Used input:

```
array = np.array([[[1,2,3,10], [4,5,6,11], [7,8,9,12]],
                  [[1,2,3,10], [4,5,6,11], [7,8,9,12]]])
lst = [50, 60, 70]
```

Comment: It worked. I could not have found it myself. I will explore "broadcasting", thank you for putting the link to the documentation.